# Visualforce rerender selectList after clicking command button

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to get a selectList to reset to None after clicking a CommandButton. Right now after I save the button, it just stays on the last value picked. I want to keep the values that were generated from the class, just reset it to none. I've tried using rerender on as many places around the selectList that I can think of but it's not working.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true" standardStylesheets="true">
<script>
    function changeValue(input, textid) {
        document.getElementById(textid).value = input.value;
    }   

    function show_alert()
    {
    var msg = "Your survey has been saved.";
    alert(msg);
    }
</script>
<apex:form >
    <apex:outputPanel id="MBTRList">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!hideStuff}">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Build Form" action="{!callTwoMethods}" rerender="MBTRList,Form,formButton" rendered="{!hideStuff}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="formButton">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showStuff}">   
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Form" action="{!saveList}" onclick="show_alert()" rerender="mainForm,selectList,Form,selectListBlock"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="Form">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showStuff}">  
           <apex:pageBlockSection id="selectListBlock">
               <apex:selectList label="Please select your name: " value="{!inputText3}" size="1" multiselect="false" required="true">
                   <apex:selectOptions id="selectList" value="{!List}"></apex:selectOptions>
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!showMainPanel}" reRender="mainForm,Form"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="mainForm">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showMain}">
    <table>
        <tr>
    <td style="font-weight: bold;" colspan="10">
    * 1. Pain Scale
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">No Pain</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">1</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">2</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">3</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">4</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">    Interrupts some<br/>activities  </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">6</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">7</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">8</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">9</td>
    <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:bottom; width:9%;">As bad as it could be</td>
</tr>
<tr  style="background-color:#eeeeee">
    <td style="text-align:center;">Before session
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!painBefore}" id="painBefore" /></td>

    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale Before" value="No Pain"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale1 Before" value="1"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale2 Before" value="2"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale3 Before" value="3"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale4 Before" value="4"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale5 Before" value="Interrupts some activities"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale6 Before" value="6"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale7 Before" value="7"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale8 Before" value="8"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale9 Before" value="9"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="radio" onclick="changeValue(this,'{!$Component.painBefore}');" name="Pain Scale Before" id="Pain Scale10 Before" value="As bad as it could be"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class wrapperClassController {

public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}
public Boolean showStuff { get; set; }
public Boolean showMain { get; set; }
public Boolean hideStuff { get; set; }
public String inputText1{get;set;}
public String painBefore{get;set;}
public Id inputText3{get;set;}

public wrapperClassController(){
    showStuff = false;
    showMain = false;
    hideStuff = true;
}

public PageReference callTwoMethods() {

      toggleContent();
      processSelected();

      return null;

}

public PageReference toggleContent() {
        showStuff = true;
        hideStuff = false;
    return null;
}

public PageReference showMainPanel() {
        showMain = true;
    return null;
}

public List<cContact> getContacts(){
    if(contactList == null){
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        for(Contact c:[select Id, Name from Contact 
                       WHERE RecordTypeId = '012f10000000LFN']){
                           contactList.add(new cContact(c));
                       }
    }
    return contactList;
}

public PageReference processSelected(){
    List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    for(cContact cCon:getContacts()){
        if(cCon.selected == true){
            selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public List<selectOption> getList(){
    List<selectOption> selectedContacts = new List<selectOption>();
    selectedContacts.add(new selectOption('', '--None--'));
    for(cContact cCon:getContacts()){
        if(cCon.selected == true){
            selectedContacts.add(new selectOption(cCon.con.Id,cCon.con.Name));
        }
    }
    return selectedContacts;
}

public PageReference saveList(){
    MBTR_Forms_Docs_Evals__c MBTR = new MBTR_Forms_Docs_Evals__c(); //  Either salesObj is standard or custom object

    MBTR.Participant_s_initials__c = inputText1;  // Field Assignment
    MBTR.Pain_Scale_Before__c = painBefore;
    MBTR.Contact__c = inputText3;
    MBTR.RecordTypeId = '012f10000000L9K';
    insert MBTR; // DML Operations
    showMain = false;
    return null;

} 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rest the value of `SelectList`. You need to clear the old value. Only `rerender` will not work here. Unless you do so it won't get rest to None.

So add this line in your `saveList` method.

```
public PageReference saveList(){
    //other code will remain here
    inputText3 = '';
}
```